# How to do thread management in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design

We use `pthread` for thread management in C based systems. pthread is in general compilable by C++ compiler (like g++). However, what are the better ways of abstractions for threads in C++?

Also, for making any system to be working in a multi-threaded system, it is also important to make thread safe. What are the standard libraries that requires alternative (installs) to be thread safe or are they unsafe for multi-threaded environments?

Is smart pointers, templates require special measures to make it safe?

What are the best practices for the thread managements in C++?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use C++11, threading is part of standard library and components where it makes sense like smart pointers are thread-safe (collections generally require you lock them yourself).

If you are using Boost, have a look at [boost.thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html). It is base for what was standardized in C++11 (most new things in C++11 come from boost).

Comment: is this threading already supported by all common compilers?

Comment: @stijn: This is a standard C++ library (not compiler) feature and many compilers can be used with multiple standard C++ libraries. The GNU stdlibc++ (that comes with gcc) mostly supports it as does (except `atomic`) the LLVM libcxx (that comes with clang; clang can also be used with the GNU one). I don't know about Visual Studio 2010, but you can use the Boost version (which is interchangeable) with almost any compiler (no `atomic` there either though). There is also [Apache stdcxx](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/) implementation that can be used with most compilers.

Comment: thanks for clearing that out. And yes I meant the lib, not the compiler ;P

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Jan Hudec wrote, if you want to use even higher level of abstraction (which can be a good idea) take a look at [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/). Microsoft has [Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx) which is also excellent but MS specific.

Comment: or there's OpenMP which is built into the VC compiler.